# General distributional solution of the Airy Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I prove that the Airy equation
$$ \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-xu = 0 $$
 has at least two linear independent solutions?[image]

Once I've found it how can I prove the existence of two independent DISTRIBUTIONAL solutions

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about the Airy equation. It is second-order linear equation. All such equations have two linearly independent solutions. Any book on differential equations will prove this.

Comment: Even if it is a distribution?

Comment: The two solutions are nice smooth -- even analytic --- functions. They can be regarded as distributions of course, but I feel that I am not understanding what it is that you are worried about . Why do distributionbs come into this? Are you perhaps thinking of them as some non-normalizable "eigenfunctions" of Schroedinger equation?  Such generalized eigenfunctions can be  thought of as distributions in a rigged Hilbert space.

Comment: I asked about distributional solutions of the Airy equation. I found the solution thanks to the fourier transform, but I am not sure how to demonstrate that there are at least two independent solutions

Comment: @MargeA : Then please demonstrate this solution process ([edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3064316/edit) the question text) and highlight the point where you are uncertain about the existence of two basis solutions.

Comment: In $x=0$ the second term of the differential equation vanishes. Could a Dirac delta or a combination of derivatives of the Dirac delta be in the solution? My question arises because we know that the only distribution that is only supported in $ x=0$ is the delta distribution.

Comment: @diec_ : Free-form association is all nice and well, but what exactly has your comment to do with the question?

Comment: @LutzL Sorry, I was just a bit confused. I thought about different differential equation.

Comment: You get two linear independent solutions by replacing your integral's limits of $\pm \infty$  contours that run between any pair of the points $\infty,  e^{2\pi i/3} \infty, e^{-2\pi i/3}\infty$. The sum of all three contours is zero because the integrand is an entire function.   I don't think that there are any singular distributional solutions  in the  weak sense  of the equation.