# Find the solution of a distributional differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, distribution-theory, airy-functions

How can I find the solution of the distributional equation

> $$ \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-xu = 0 $$

And prove that there are at least two linear independent solutions? I've tried to to with the Fourier Transform but it is not possible to find the solution that diverges as $x$ tends to infinity, because the Fourier Transform is not defined for such functions. (they are so called Airy functions). I've tried also to solve it by testing the equation with an appropriate test function, but I'm stuck. [image]

This is the method used. Once I've found Ai(x), I cannot prove that there are two independent solutions.

Comment: You may try this form $u=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_nx^n$, and seek for the recurrence relation between $a_n$'s.

Comment: http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0202.pdf

Comment: Why do you need test functions? Classical solutions work just fine, and you argue like you would for any linear second-order ODE. For example, the solutions with $(u(0),u'(0))$ equal to $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, respectively, are linearly independent.

Comment: If you do not specify what solution method you use and exactly what the point is you wonder about, you will always get the same answer that you already got for your first identical question, before you added the Fourier calculations.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE : The original question has been modified and completed after discussion. As a consequence my answer below is no longer well-adapted.

> $$ \frac{d^2u}{dx^2}-xu = 0 $$

This ODE is known as Airy equation : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html

There is no closed form for the solutions with a finite number of elementary functions.

A closed form requires special functions, namely the Airy functions Ai$(x)$ and Bi$(x)$
$$u(x)=c_1\text{Ai}(x)+c_2\text{Bi}(x)$$

The Airy functions are related to some other special functions, especially the Bessel functions of first kind.

To express the solutions with elementary fonctions only, infinite series are required. The calculus is rather boring. See Eqs.$(2-26)$ in the above reference.

About properties of Airy functions : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryFunctions.html

Comment: But how can I find the distributional solution? If u Is a distribution, I am not sure the canonical method is the easiest or if it even works

Comment: To solve this kind of ODE, with any method you  cannot avoid either an infinite series or a special function as pointed out.

Comment: May be, your question is not well posed in the context of distributions. Elaborate the hypothesis and the equation model for the particular problem that you have to solve.

Comment: It is an exam exercise given by my mathematics methods of physics professor. He asked to find the distributional solution of the Airy equation, nothing more

Comment: Then I suppose that you refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Test_functions_and_distributions . So you have to apply your course book. In addition to your question, show what you have done (use the "edit" button) and show exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: I am stuck at the end. I found Ai(x) but not the other solution.

Comment: This is explained by Lutz in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064316/general-distributional-solution-of-the-airy-equation